# HTTPS Redirection not working in Lightppd

Tags: lighttpd

I need to redirect https://www.mysite.com/folder/subfolder to https://www.mysite.com/folder/ in lighttpd. I've tried the following:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "https://www.mysite.com/folder/folder" {
  url.redirect = (
    ".*" => "https://www.mysite.com/folder/" 
  )
}
```

but it did not work.

Can anyone please tell me the correct syntax in Lighttpd?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because the mod_redirect module isn't available (it's typically disabled by default).

1. If you're on a UNIX platform open **modules.conf**, probably in /etc/lighttpd (on Windows the settings are in lighttpd.conf).
2. Find **server.modules** and uncomment **mod_redirect**
3. Then add a redirect rule to your **lighttpd.conf**. I've implemented my rule in a slightly different way to you - I redirect all http:// requests for a given host to their https:// equivalent.

**modules.conf**

```
server.modules = (   
    "mod_access",  
    "mod_proxy",
    "mod_accesslog",  
#   "mod_alias",  
#   "mod_auth",  
#   "mod_evasive",  
    "mod_redirect",  
    "mod_rewrite"  
#   "mod_setenv",  
#   "mod_usertrack",  
)
```

**lightttpd.conf**

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^subdomain.server.com" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```